# Why TumblingProcessingTimeWindows not assign TimeWindow' start time using current processing time?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Belowing is the related code.
Question:
Why not just let `Timedow'startTime = context.getCurrentProcessingTime()`?
One curcirmstance here:
now=10s, size=3s, according to code belowing, TimeWindow'startTime will be 9s, and endTime will be 12s, and elements with processingTime between 12s and 13s will not go to this window which is unexpected.

What expected is TimeWindow startTime is now 10s and endTime is 13s, and thus elements with processingTime between 10s and 13s will all go to the same window.

```
public class TumblingProcessingTimeWindows extends WindowAssigner<Object, TimeWindow> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final long size;
    private final long offset;
    ...
    public Collection<TimeWindow> assignWindows(Object element, long timestamp, WindowAssignerContext context) {
        long now = context.getCurrentProcessingTime();
        long start = TimeWindow.getWindowStartWithOffset(now, this.offset, this.size);
        return Collections.singletonList(new TimeWindow(start, start + this.size));
    }
```